# Algorithm to calculate how much of text A is in text B?

Tags: algorithm, text, language-agnostic, text-comparison

I need to calculate how much of a block of text (`A`) is in another block of text (`B`). Simple algorithms like soundex aren't providing great results for me as text `B` has additional text within it that isn't/shouldn't be in text `A`, which throws my figures off. I need to ensure a certain percentage of `A` is within `B`, and ignore the additions to `B`.

My first thought for a simple algorithm that might work well in my case would be to split `A` into sentences, note the total number of sentences, then search `B` for an instance of each sentence to provide a percentage. While this should work it feels quite hacky, and I'm sure someone more intelligent than I has devised an algorithm to provide a better calculation on a similar principle.

Comment: Try [diff match patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)?

Comment: There is a whole branch doing this, it is called [Plagiarism detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection)

Comment: Locality Sensitive Hashing might be an overkill, but you can get ideas from it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

Answer (score 0):

[Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) looks like best suited for your purposes.